# Makefile giving error with No target for rule G++

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Complete Makefile noob here.  I cannot figure out why this is happening, but I think it is whitespace/tab.  I have this Makefile:

```
BUILD_DIR = build/debug
CC = g++
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_NAME = play
INCLUDE_PATHS = -Iinclude
LIBRARY_PATHS = -Llib
COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -O0 -g
LINKER_FLAGS = -lsdl2

all: $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(SRC_FILES) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)
```

and it gives this error:
`` make: *** No rule to make target `g++', needed by `all'.  Stop. ``

If I move the string to the bottom with tab and just use `all:` on one line and the string on the other it gives this:

`Makefile:12: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

And I thought Python was crazy about space. Cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put commands on a new line:

```
all:
    $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(SRC_FILES) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)
```

and make sure it is indented with tab, not space

It is also not python, it's make

You couuld also use a semicolon to separate dependencies from commands like this:

```
all: $(SRC_FILES); $(CC) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(SRC_FILES) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OBJ_NAME)
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Makefile:12: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: Did you make it a tab instead of space? Seems like stackoverflow converts everything to space so you'll need to fix it after pasting it

Comment: I know...I was just saying that I thought Python was nuts about space, but this is way more nuts about space/tab, etc

Comment: Yeah... I made it a tab.  It's a 2 space tab though,  need to be 4?

Comment: A tab is a different character than space. Let me add another section to the answer since there is another way

Comment: We are good.  Thanks Gavin.  VSCode had tabs converting to spaces.  Thanks a bunch!